# Selection Border has 100% feather

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So this is what I'm doing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why does it feather the border? I cannot figure out how to fix this. I've done some searching and can find no information on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should right click the selection and choose stroke (or Edit->Stroke) and it will make a stroke with no feather.

UPDATE:
If you don't want a stroke then make a selection and then make another shape with the pen tool or box and subtract the shape from the selection. I made a video on how [youtube.com/watch?v=NCuWRaWRIZ4](http://youtube.com/watch?v=NCuWRaWRIZ4)

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I don't actually want to _stroke_ the selection, only _make_ the selection. I need to use the bordered selection for other operations. I could make a new layer, stroke the selection, magic select the stroked area then go back to the previous layer but that doesn't result in a very clean selection due to the stroke being antialiased. Definitely the best option so far though.

Comment: So don't call it a stroke - call it a border. This "border" (which is a stroke) will function the same. You can fill the center or the border (stroke) with the bucket tool independently. Only difference is that it will have hard edges and not feathered.

Comment: But I didn't _want_ a stroke. I didn't want to fill anything. I needed a selection. I don't remember what I wanted to do; it was for copying or blurring or something, not filling with a solid colour.

Comment: I updated my answer with a new solution.

Comment: OMG you did that the most complicated way possible. Just hold Alt and draw another selection inside the first one to subtract! But that doesn't help me. I had a complex selection that involved painstakingly using combinations of magnetic lasso and manual freehand selection and I just needed the border of the selection. I never though it could be so difficult. In the end I just used Gimp because it's a lot better than PS in many ways, but it sucked because I had to make the selection all over again.

Comment: To be clear, I appreciate you trying to help, but I use PS a LOT and I'm pretty sure I will have thought of anything you can suggest.

Comment: Then your question is irrelevant because you want the border tool to do something it was not meant to do.

Comment: Well... no. Read the question again. I didn't ask how to achieve the selection I wanted, I asked why the border tool has a 100% feather and how I can change that. I get the feeling you downvoted my question, which is fine with me, but I think you should review posts more carefully before voting.

Comment: That border tool HAS a feather - that's how that function works. Yes, I know about ALT to deselect a selection, I was being more complex because I didn't know exactly what you wanted. If it's just the border-feather thing, the correct answer is simple: "That way will always give a feather". If that answer satisfies you, let me update my answer so you can mark it as correct. Yes, I down-voted but went to up-vote back but since it's been 12 hours ago it won't let me unless you edit the question